# pure css javascript not working after deployment Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, yui-pure-css

I am using pure css and bootstrap in one of my Django project, and everything is fine when I run in my local machine. But after I deployed, it looks different. Snapshot of the font from my local machine is

[image]

but the font-width increased after i deployed it in digital ocean. Snapshot of how it looks right now after deployment is

[image]

It is live at http://getfbstuff.com . I am posting the html code of head

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <title>Get Facebook Stuff</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'downloader/pure-market.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'downloader/baby-blue.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'downloader/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'downloader/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'downloader/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css' %}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'downloader/style.css' %}">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.2.1/pure-min.css">
      <script src="http://use.typekit.net/ajf8ggy.js"></script>
      <script>
          try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) {}
      </script>

</head>
```

i think problem is with this javascript

```
 <script src="http://use.typekit.net/ajf8ggy.js"></script>
 <script>
     try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) {}
 </script>
```

Don't know what to do.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, try putting *console.log(e);* in your catch block. That might tell you something useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Chrome, Firefox or IE (with web developer tools) installed see the console debugger, there's a few dependencies not loading at their expected paths.

Have you setup your production server to [serve static content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)? You also seem to have a cross domain issue.

Comment: may be but home page of purecss.io does same and their site renders fonts properly

Comment: The included type is rejected by the hosting server (hence the 403) have you got a legitimate account to embed the font?

Comment: No. I just took code from purecss.io , but then it should also not work in localhost right?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having trouble with such problem, I fixed mine after realizing that files are served differently in a production environment. It suddenly dawned on me to try running "python manage.py collectstatic" again, and that solved the problem for me.

Apparently the changes in my CSS file didn't take effect, because the changed file was located in the static folder and just weren't delivered directly.